# How to share react-native app to client for them to test

Tags: android, react-native, mobile-application

I am developing a react-native application. My question is how can i share my app to my client so that they can test it on their devices and beta test the app? My client uses android and specific Samsung Galaxy s8.

Can I also do this in a way so that when I push a new update the client can receive that update automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set up open, closed, or internal testing using Google Play console as documented in this help page:

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en

so your selected customers needs to sign up and voila. And they will get the update if you go that way.

Alternatively, you can hand them `*.apk` file and tell how to sideload, yet that less user friendly and it won't come with updates unless you app is released or they join test program.